# OpenJPA + Log4j2

Tags: log4j2, openjpa

Having problem with integrating OpenJPA with log4j2.

OpenJPA + log4j worked fined

```
<appender name="OPENJPA_LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="5MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="file" value="./logs/openjpa.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="openjpa.jdbc.SQL" additivity="false">
    <level value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="OPENJPA_LOG" />
</logger>
```

But it is not working with log4j2.

```
<RollingFile name="OPENJPA_LOG" fileName="./logs/openjpa.log"
    append="true" filePattern="./logs/openjpa.%i.log.gz"
    ignoreExceptions="false">
    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %c [%thread] - %m%n</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
</RollingFile>

<Logger name="openjpa.jdbc.SQL" level="TRACE" additivity="false" >
    <AppenderRef ref="OPENJPA_LOG" />
</Logger>
```

How to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have issues with this you have to double check that in the persistence.xml you set `<property name="openjpa.Log" value="slf4j"/>`. 
Indeed open jpa is not compatible with log4j2 natively so if you use `<property name="openjpa.Log" value="log4j"/>` you will run into a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Priority.

Once openjpa logs are route properly to slf4j it is ok. I hope your application use sllf4j.

Be sure to use proper versions of log4j2 slf4j and bridge and remove all previous log4j1.x and old slf4j dependencies.